# Is it possible to specify which events trigger tooltips in Vega.js?

Tags: javascript, vega

First part of the question is: What events trigger tooltips? According to the [Vega documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/rect/), tooltips are triggered by "mouse hover" events. Based on my experiments, this includes only mousemove and mouseout events.

Second part: Is it possible to specify an [event stream](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/event-streams/) that triggers tooltips? Say, for example I had two panels in a visualization: one, a map of U.S. counties and two, a scatter plot of the same counties. It may be useful to have a tooltip show on the map when hovering over the scatter plot, and vice versa.